# Programming function keys

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, to program a function key?
I'd like to map a function key to "SELECT * FROM dbo."

Comment: I take it you want to do a keystroke and have the text show up in the screen, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a free management studio tool called "SSMS Tools Pack" from Mladen Prajdic.  It has a feature called SQL snippets where you can map snippets of SQL code to predefined keystrokes ("ssf" + ENTER" will do what you want using the tool).

I use it every day at different clients and its part of my SQL toolkit.  Check it out here:
[www.ssmstoolspack.com](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com).

Eric

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is  Tools-->Options-->Enviroment-->Keyboard

there are already a bunch there , you can type anything you want in the Stored Procedure column. However that will just execute, I guess you can do a PRINT 'SELECT * FROM fbo.' in your case

[image]

Comment: I suspect the OP wants the text to be added to the query pane, not the results pane

Answer (score 2):

It's outside of the studio but I use AutoHotKey (google it).  You can write little keyword macros.  Even launch applications with a few keystrokes.  All in an effort to reduce time on the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS:

- Tools
- Options
- Keyboard
- Select the desire shortcut (only 12 options, 3 of which are hard-coded and cannot be changed, which is better than none, but not by much)
- Enter what you'd want run (for example, I have CTRL+0 set to "USE tempdb"
- Save

These hotkeys will not be available to *currently* opened query windows, only windows opened after you've created them.

Note that if you make it a procedure call, such as as CTRL+1's "sp_who", hilight a block of text, and hit the hot key, the highlit text is passed in as a parameter to the procedure. Try it with CTRL+1 and see. (...and you get lots of fun and games with embedded periods which can be overridden by [bracketing it], but you'll find out about that as you go along.)

Answer (score 0):

SSMSBoost add-in has this feaure:
you can define tokens and replacements for them. Example:

**sel**   ->   `select * from`

**upd**   ->   `update # set  where`

symbol "**#**" defines, where cursor will be placed after replacement is done. You can define your own replacements.

There are certainlny much more features, for example Hitting **F2** in SQL Editor will immediately script object, located at cursor. It is something like "go to definition" function in Visual Studio.